# check for module position not to be set

Tags: php, joomla

Here is the code I use to count modules in joomla, to see if it's available or not.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'right' )) : ?>
```

Now I want the contrary of this, like, when the module is not set..

Should I use something like:

```
<?php if (!$this->countModules( 'right' )) : ?>
```

I mean, what should I use in order to achieve it? I suppose, well not suppose but the way I wrote is for sure wrong.

Comment: I don't see any issue with this supposing that `countModules` returns either 0 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php if ($this->countModules( 'right' )) : ?>
```

checks for `true`

and its opposite is this

```
<?php if (!$this->countModules( 'right' )) : ?>
```

it checks for `false`

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/W2Am6k

Comment: Great :)
i wasn't that wrong then.. thank you very much, i'm accepting in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if ($this->countModules( 'right' ) <= 0) :
```

Or this (more readable IMHO):

```
if ( empty($this->countModules( 'right' )) ) :
```

By the way `countModules()` just returns the number of modules enabled in that module position, so if the return value is 0 it means no modules are enabled.

http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/countModules

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php 

    if( $this->countModules( 'right' ) < 1 ) : echo 'No right modules'; endif; 

?>
```

"!" stands for false, its a boolean. "< 1" represents a real number, in other words, represents anything less than 1. If you're using Joomla's "countModules" function, we're counting modules, so, it makes sense to use numeric comparatives.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if ($this->countModules( 'right' )) : 
    //there are modules
else :
    //no modules
endif;
?>
```

Comment: What is difference b/w above code and `if (!$this->countModules( 'right' )) :`?